# How to support different screen sizes in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

I'm trying to find out, how My application can support all different screen sizes on Android,

I tried to do this `android:scaleType="fitXY"`  but it doesn't work

I tried to change the dimes.xml file , but adding `<dimen name="default_padding">11dp</dimen>`

So can you please give me an idea on how can my application support different screen sizes in Android

Comment: Actually are you trying to support screen size for images or the whole application

Comment: The whole application, with Images I think I should put each size in the Right drawable file.

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I did, but I couldn't understand what I should really do